# magento 2.3 overide date calendar class

Tags: magento2, date, class, calendar

I am trying to override a date calendar class in Magento.
But when I try doing it the date input from the product page disappears.
Basic I want to override the date calendar script to add custom settings to it.
I added a hidden span to see if my changes get out.

c3m\custommodule\Model\Date

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace c3m\custommodule\Model;
//namespace Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html;

/**
 * Date element block
 */
class Date extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date
{
    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '<input type="text" name="' . $this->getName() . '" id="' . $this->getId() . '" ';
        $html .= 'value="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getValue()) . '" ';
        $html .= 'class="' . $this->getClass() . '" ' . $this->getExtraParams() . '/> ';
        $calendarYearsRange = $this->getYearsRange();
        $changeMonth = $this->getChangeMonth();
        $changeYear = $this->getChangeYear();
        $maxDate = $this->getMaxDate();
        $showOn = $this->getShowOn();
        $firstDay = $this->getFirstDay();

        $html .= '<span style="display:none;">123</span><script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
                    $("#' .
            $this->getId() .
            '").calendar({
                        showsTime: ' .
            ($this->getTimeFormat() ? 'true' : 'false') .
            ',
                        ' .
            ($this->getTimeFormat() ? 'timeFormat: "' .
            $this->getTimeFormat() .
            '",' : '') .
            '
                        dateFormat: "' .
            $this->getDateFormat() .
            '",
                        buttonImage: "' .
            $this->getImage() .
            '",
                        ' .
            ($calendarYearsRange ? 'yearRange: "' .
            $calendarYearsRange .
            '",' : '') .
            '
                        buttonText: "' .
            (string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                'Select Date'
            ) .
            '"' . ($maxDate ? ', maxDate: "' . $maxDate . '"' : '') .
            ($changeMonth === null ? '' : ', changeMonth: ' . $changeMonth) .
            ($changeYear === null ? '' : ', changeYear: ' . $changeYear) .
            ($showOn ? ', showOn: "' . $showOn . '"' : '') .
            ($firstDay ? ', firstDay: ' . $firstDay : '') .
            '})
            });
            </script>';

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Convert special characters to HTML entities
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEscapedValue()
    {
        if ($this->getFormat() && $this->getValue()) {
            return strftime($this->getFormat(), strtotime($this->getValue()));
        }
        return $this->escapeHtml($this->getValue());
    }

    /**
     * Produce and return block's html output
     *
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

c3m\custommodule\etc\di

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date" type="c3m\custommodule\Model\Date"/>
</config>
```

You can see at the picture I added that the calendar input is gone.
[image]

I have set developer mode on and some errors came when i reloaded the page:

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class c3m\custommodule\Model\Date does not exist
```

Tried making a new plugin just with first letter uppercase instead of small like
C3m\Custommodule
but its still saying class does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class must extend,

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date
```

Instead of

> \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: Hello @aravind tried your changes, the calendar input is still missing for some reason.
you can see my changes at first post.

Comment: Did you get any errors in logs? or browser console?

Comment: i cleaned the logs and no errors was found when i reloaded the page, but a bit later there was two errors: main.CRITICAL: Class c3m\custommodule\Model\Date does not exist [] [] and main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date [] []